# Grep: show only what matched in a regex group

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How can I grep only what matched in a regex group?

for example, get from:

```
some text ... <a href='...'/user/9082/>... </a>
```

only numbers from `/user/9082/`:

```
9082
```

What I've tried:

```
echo "some text ... <a href='...'/user/9082/>3435435345345</a>" | grep -Eo "/user/([0-9]+)/"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/11130/can-gnu-grep-output-a-selected-group

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed`.

```
$ echo "some text ... <a href='...'/user/9082/>3435435345345</a>" |
> sed -E 's|^.*/user/([0-9]+)/.*$|\1|'
9082
```

You say "I can use also `sed` and other methods" implying you are aware `sed` is the right tool, but that you don't want to use it.  Can you elaborate on why?  `grep` is for searching, `sed` is for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bash regex:

```
str="some text ... <a href='...'/user/9082/>... </a>"
re="/user/([0-9]+)/"
[[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`

```
echo "some text ... <a href='...'/user/9082/>3435435345345</a>"  | grep -o '\/user\/[0-9]\+\/'
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for, he wants only the number, your answer prints `/user/9082/`.